# Avoiding framework-imposed circular dependencies in Guice

Tags: java, swing, guice

**Please note:** Although this question specifically calls out Swing, I *believe* this to be a pure Guice (**4.0**) question at heart and which highlights a potential generic issue with Guice and other opinionated frameworks.

---

In Swing, you have your application UI, which extends `JFrame`:

```
// Pseudo-code
class MyApp extends JFrame {
    // ...
}
```

Your app (`JFrame`) needs a menubar:

```
// Pseudo-code
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar()

JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu('File')

JMenu manageMenu = new JMenu('Manage')
JMenuItem widgetsSubmenu = new JMenuItem('Widgets')
manageMenu.add(widgetsSubmenu)

menuBar.add(fileMenu)
menuBar.add(manageMenu)

return menuBar
```

And your menu items need action listeners, many of which will updated your app's `contentPane`:

```
widgetsSubmenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // Remove all the elements from the main contentPane
        yourApp.contentPane.removeAll()

        // Now add a new panel to the contentPane
        yourApp.contentPane.add(someNewPanel)
    }
})
```

**And so there is intrinsically a circular dependency:**

1. Your app/`JFrame` needs a `JMenuBar` instance
2. Your `JMenuBar` needs 0+ `JMenus` and `JMenuItems`
3. Your `JMenuItems` (well, the ones that will update your `JFrame`'s `contentPane`') need action listeners
4. And then, in order to update the `JFrame`'s `contentPane`, these action listeners need to reference your `JFrame`

Take the following module:

```
// Pseudo-code
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    void configure() {
        // ...
    }

    @Provides
    MyApp providesMyApp(JMenuBar menuBar) {
        // Remember MyApp extends JFrame...
        return new MyApp(menuBar, ...)
    }

    @Provides
    JMenuBar providesMenuBar(@Named('widgetsListener') ActionListener widgetsMenuActionListener) {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar()

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu('File')

        JMenu manageMenu = new JMenu('Manage')
        JMenuItem widgetsSubmenu = new JMenuItem('Widgets')
        widgetsSubmenu.addActionListener(widgetsMenuActionListener)
        manageMenu.add(widgetsSubmenu)

        menuBar.add(fileMenu)
        menuBar.add(manageMenu)

        return menuBar
    }

    @Provides
    @Named('widgetsListener')
    ActionListener providesWidgetsActionListener(Myapp myApp, @Named('widgetsPanel') JPanel widgetsPanel) {
        new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                // Here is the circular dependency. MyApp needs an instance of this listener to
                // to be instantiated, but this listener depends on a MyApp instance in order to
                // properly update the main content pane...
                myApp.contentPane.removeAll()
                myApp.contentPane.add(widgetsPanel)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce circular dependency errors at runtime, such as:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventDispatcher" com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Tried proxying com.me.myapp.MyApp to support a circular dependency, but it is not an interface.
    while locating com.me.myapp.MyApp
```

So I ask: **what's the way of circumventing this?** Does Guice have an API or extension library for dealing with this sort of problem? Is there a way to refactor the code to break the circular dependency? Some other solution?

---

#### Update

Please see my [guice-swing-example](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/guice-swing-example) project on GitHub for a SSCCE.

Comment: Hmmm... you write this as a java issue, but yet the SSCCE is in Groovy. Sorry, but I won't learn Groovy to help you out. You should probably have asked this as a groovy question or made the SSCCE as a Java example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several techniques available to refactor a circular dependency so that it is no longer circular, and [Guice docs recommend doing that whenever possible](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CyclicDependencies). For when that is not possible, the error message Guice provided hints at the Guice way to resolve this in general: separate your API from your implementation by using an interface.

Strictly speaking it is only necessary to do this for one class in the circle, but it may improve modularity and ease of writing test code to do it for most or every class. Create an interface, `MyAppInterface`, declare in it every method that your action listeners need to call directly (`getContentPane()` seems to be the only one in the code you posted), and have `MyApp` implement it. Then bind `MyAppInterface` to `MyApp` in your module configuration (in your case simply changing the return type of `providesMyApp` should do it), declare the action listener provider to take a `MyAppInterface`, and run it. You might also need to switch some other places in your code from `MyApp` to `MyAppInterface`, depends on the details.

Doing this will allow Guice itself to break the circular dependency for you. When it sees the circular dependency, it will generate a new zero-dependency implementing class of `MyAppInterface` that acts as a proxy wrapper, pass an instance of that into the action listener provider, fill out the dependency chain from there until it can make a real `MyApp` object, and then it will stick the `MyApp` object inside Guice's generated object which will forward all method calls to it.

Though I used `MyAppInterface` above, a more common naming pattern would be to actually use the `MyApp` name for the interface and rename the existing `MyApp` class to `MyAppImpl`.

Note that Guice's method of automatic circular dependency breaking requires that you not call any methods on the generated proxy object until after initialization is complete, because it won't have a wrapped object to forward them to until then.

Edit: I don't have Groovy or Gradle ready to try to run your SSCCE for testing, but I think you are very close to breaking the circle already. Annotate the `DefaultFizzClient` class and each of your `@Provides` methods with `@Singleton`, and remove the `menuBar` parameter from `provideExampleApp`, and I think that should make it work.

`@Singleton`: A class or provider method should be marked `@Singleton` when only a single instance of it should be made. This is important when it is injected in multiple different places or requested multiple times. With `@Singleton`, Guice makes one instance, saves a reference to it, and uses that one instance every time. Without, it makes a new separate instance for each reference. Conceptually, it's a matter of whether you are defining "how to make an X" or "this here is *the* X". It seems to me that the UI elements you're creating fall in the latter category - the singular menu bar for your app, not any arbitrary menu bar, etc.

Removing `menuBar`: You've already commented out the one and only line in that method that uses it. Simply delete the parameter from the method declaration. As for how to get the menu bar into the app anyway, that is already handled by the `addMenuToFrame` method combined with the `requestInjection(this)` call.

Perhaps it might help to do a run through of the logic Guice will go through if these alterations are made:

1. When you create the injector with an `ExampleAppModule`, it calls your module's `configure()` method. This sets up some bindings and tells Guice that, whenever it's done with all the bindings setup, it should scan the `ExampleAppModule` instance for fields and methods annotated with `@Inject` and fill them in.
2. `configure()` returns and, with bindings setup complete, Guice honors the `requestInjection(this)` call. It scans and finds that `addMenuToFrame` is annotated with `@Inject`. Inspecting that method, Guice finds that an `ExampleApp` instance and a `JMenuBar` instance are needed in order to call it.
3. Guice looks for a way to make an `ExampleApp` instance and finds the `provideExampleApp` method. Guice examines that method and finds that a `FizzClient` instance is needed to call it.
4. Guice looks for a way to make a `FizzClient` instance and finds the class binding to `DefaultFizzClient`. `DefaultFizzClient` has a default no-args constructor, so Guice just calls that to get an instance.
5. Having acquired a `FizzClient` instance, Guice is now able to call `provideExampleApp`. It does so, thereby acquiring an `ExampleApp` instance.
6. Guice still needs a `JMenuBar` in order to call `addMenuToFrame`, so it looks for a way to make one and finds the `providesMenuBar` method. Guice examines that method and notes that it needs an `ActionListener` named "widgetsMenuActionListener".
7. Guice looks for a way to create an `ActionListener` named "widgetsMenuActionListener" and finds the `providesWidgetsMenuActionListener` method. Guice examines that method and finds that it needs an `ExampleApp` instance and a `JPanel` named "widgetsPanel". It already has an `ExampleApp` instance, acquired in step 5, and it got that from something marked as `@Singleton`, so it reuses the same instance rather than calling `provideExampleApp` again.
8. Guice looks for a way to make a `JPanel` named "widgetsPanel" and finds the `providesWidgetPanel` method. This method has no parameters, so Guice just calls it and acquires the `JPanel` it needs.
9. Having acquired a `JPanel` with the right name in addition to the already-made `ExampleApp`, Guice calls `providesWidgetsMenuActionListener`, thereby acquiring a named `ActionListener` instance.
10. Having acquired an `ActionListener` with the right name, Guice calls `providesMenuBar`, thereby acquiring a `JMenuBar` instance.
11. Having finally, at long last, acquired both an `ExampleApp` instance and a `JMenuBar` instance, Guice calls `addMenuToFrame`, which adds the menu to the frame.
12. Now after all that has happened, your `getInstance(ExampleApp)` call in `main` gets executed. Guice checks, finds that it already has an `ExampleApp` instance from a source marked `@Singleton`, and returns that instance.

Having looked through all of that, it seems `@Singleton` is strictly necessary only on `provideExampleApp`, but I think makes sense for everything else too.

Comment: Thanks @Douglas (+1)! Two quick questions: (1) Why do you recommend annotating `providesX` methods with `@Singleton` - in other words when should one use this annotation? And (2) How could I remove the `menuBar` param from `provideExampleApp`? The app does in fact *need* a menu! Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb See my new edit, it got rather too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you do have a circular dependency, it can't be a creational circular dependency - since otherwise you wouldn't be able to create that cycle of objects at all.

You can perform post-creation configuration by requesting injection on a module. For example, you can use this to add the `JMenuBar` to the `JFrame`:

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override void configure() {
    requestInjection(this);
  }

  @Inject void addMenuToFrame(JFrame frame, JMenuBar menu) {
    frame.setMenuBar(menu);
  }
}
```

I've not tested this to see if it works (as you've not given enough code to try it on) - so you might need to experiment with where the right place is to break the current cycle in order to subsequently join it like this - but something like this should work for you.

---

I've answered a few other questions about injecting into guice modules like this - [maybe have a look at those too](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3788176+%5Bjava%5D+guice), since there are some great tips from others about this too, rather than me trying and failing to repeat them correctly here.

---

I've been playing with this a bit more to help my understanding, and I've found that you need your `JFrame` and `JMenuBar` to be bound in singleton scope for this to work usefully, because the method injection occurs upon creation of the injector, not upon subsequent creation of `JFrame` and `JMenuBar` instances (probably obviously).

Comment: Thanks @Andy Turner (+1) - I'll give it a whirl when I get home tonight. If it's still not working I'll update my question with a link to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) dummy project on GitHub. **Either way:** can you confirm whether or not order matters w.r.t. the `requestInjection` invocation? Meaning, should it be called before/after other `bind(...)` calls, or does that not matter? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb it doesn't matter, since all you are doing is requesting injection at some stage. Guice will inject things when it can (or, perhaps more accurate, *once* it can - some time after the arguments are created).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Andy Turner (+1 again) - I read through your other answers and even went to the Guice docs/javadocs, and still can't make complete sense of it. Please see my update - I added a [guice-swing-example](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/guice-swing-example) project to GitHub that should show you *exactly* what I'm doing. Thanks again for all the help thus far!

Comment: Thanks for the update @Andy Turner. When you say "*...I've found that you need your `JFrame` and `JMenuBar` **to be bound in singleton scope**...*" can you elaborate what this means a bit more? Maybe even provide a pseudo-code example? I guess I'm just not seeing the forest through the trees on this one...thanks again!

Comment: Either annotate the class `@Singleton` (which you can't do for `JFrame` or `JMenuBar`), or bind it with `bind(<the key>).in(Singleton.class)` in a module. The point is that you need the instances injected into the method to be the same as the instances that you use in your GUI.

Comment: Starting to make sense...but what should I use for `<the key>`? The `JFrame`? Should I just bundle all of my `@Provides` methods up into the same monolithic one, and also annotate that with `@Singleton`? A code snippet would still be *most* awesome...

Comment: @smeeb `@Singleton` can be applied to `@Provides` methods, as per [the official docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes), so for that you can just keep your current setup and add `@Singleton` to each of your `@Provides` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this without being able to test the answer against your code, because I don't know (and I don't want to learn) Groovy.

But basically, when you have circular dependencies, the best way to break it is to use a `Provider`.

```
package so36042838;
import com.google.common.base.*;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import javax.inject.*;
public class Question {

  @Singleton public final static class A {
    B b;
    @Inject A(B b) { this.b = b; }
    void use() { System.out.println("Going through"); }
  }

  @Singleton public final static class B {
    A a;
    @Inject B(A a) { this.a = a; }
    void makeUseOfA() { a.use(); }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Guice.createInjector().getInstance(B.class).makeUseOfA(); // Produces a circular dependency error.
  }
}
```

This can then be rewritten like this:

```
package so36042838;
import com.google.common.base.*;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import javax.inject.*;
public class Question {

  @Singleton public final static class A {
    B b;
    @Inject A(B b) { this.b = b; }
    void use() { System.out.println("Going through"); }
  }

  @Singleton public final static class B {
    Supplier<A> a;
    @Inject B(Provider<A> a) { this.a = Suppliers.memoize(a::get); } // prints "Going through" as expected
    void makeUseOfA() { a.get().use(); }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Guice.createInjector().getInstance(B.class).makeUseOfA();
  }
}
```

Comment: @smeeb No, I barely try to make sense from the few Java you wrote and try to be helpful and answer anyways. Also, the criticism of your question is only to try to help you because you tag Java yet provide all the code as Groovy. I'm pointing you the flaws in your question to try to make it better. You're welcome.

Comment: @smeeb Also, I have a strong indication that it's you who downvoted my answer, yet I can't prove it, naturally. But you shouldn't downvote answers who aren't useful. This answer is correct and fixes circular dependencies, no matter how they are created.